# HashSet values are computed wrongly

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I am using HashSet which has some attributes used for all elements and then adding this Hashset to a HashMap corresponding for each element. Additionally few attributes are added for specific elements( ex THEAD ).

But the later added attribute *align* is present for both Table and THEAD. Is there something wrong in the below code.

```
private static HashMap<String, Set<String>> ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE_MAP = 
        new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

HashSet<String> tableSet = 
            new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]
            {HTMLAttributeName.style.toString(),
             HTMLAttributeName.color.toString(),
             HTMLAttributeName.dir.toString(),
             HTMLAttributeName.bgColor.toString()}));

ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE_MAP.put(HTMLElementName.TABLE, new HashSet<String>(tableSet));

// Add align only for Head 
tableSet.add(HTMLAttributeName.align.toString());

ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE_MAP.put(HTMLElementName.THEAD, tableSet);
```

Comment: I don't wish align attribute to be part of HashSet correspnding to Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as you expect. Consider the following (simplified) example which shows the behaviour:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
    HashSet<String> strings = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(array));

    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap();
    Map<String, Set<String>> newMap = new HashMap();
    Map<String, Set<String>> cloneMap = new HashMap();

    map.put("key", strings);
    newMap.put("key", new HashSet(strings));
    cloneMap.put("key", (Set<String>) strings.clone());

    strings.add("E");

    System.out.println(map); //{key=[E, b, c, a]}
    System.out.println(newMap); //{key=[b, c, a]}
    System.out.println(cloneMap); //{key=[b, c, a]}

}
```

Note that Java variables are references to objects, not objects themselves, so when you call `map.put("key", strings)` it is a reference to the underlying `HashSet` that is passed; hence when you later update the `HashSet` the `HashMap` is updated too.